# Translations of R' Hirsch

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, english, samson-raphael-hirsch

Rav Hirsch was- and is well known for his extensive literary canon, which ranges from Torah, to tefillah, to hashkafah. However, today there are a good number of English editions of some of his works. Which ones, on a book-to-book basis, are widely considered the most accurate and legible?

Comment: IMHO, a community wiki answer would probably be the best thing for this question, as likely no one person holds all (or even most!) of the information this question asks for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Hirsch Chumash* - typographically and linguistically, the [Feldheim](http://www.feldheim.com/tanach-bible/chumash/the-hirsch-chumash.html) is more legible than the Judaica Press. It was newly translated (the JP version was translated a while ago), so it will make for an easier read than the older version.
- *Nineteen Letters* - can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873066960) for pay (good print) and [here](https://archive.org/details/nineteenletterso00hirs) for free (older translation, older print; still legible though). A back-and-forth between a rabbi and a young man (both fictional) on many of the basics of Judaism.

Comment: Can you source, as requested in the question, this claim that the Feldheim is more legible?

Comment: If I had photos of the text, but I don't presently have access to either until the Fall.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, a photo woulnd't help, as the questions asks which "are widely considered the most accurate and legible". Your source would need to be a survey or something of that nature.

Comment: @msh210, why not rely on a cross-section of Mi Yodeya members?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why someone would downvote this answer....so what if it's not complete, it's a work in progress!

Comment: @Shokhet, I downvoted because it doesn't answer the question, per my previous comment.

Comment: @msh210 Aha....didn't see that nuance of the question _as written_, but I think this answer follows the intent of the question as I understood it....do you think someone should edit/advise Noach to edit his question?

Comment: @Shokhet, I believe he gets pinged by every comment on this answer.

Comment: @msh210 Even though it's a community wiki?

Comment: @Shokhet I think so.

Comment: The Feldheim translation is horrible.  I've compared it to the older blue second edition and blue one is much better in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

I can't comment on the other editions, but Rabbi Isadore Grunfeld's translation of Horeb is excellent, as is his (nearly 100 page!) introduction. I consider this sefer a must-read for all Jews, as it is a unique, comprehensive and compelling philosophy of Judaism, as well as a concise summary of all halacha relevant to the life of an observant Jew. The sentences are long and flowery, and thus take considerable concentration to follow. But I can't imagine how a faithful translation could cut his poetic 19th-century German sentences into 21st-century style sentences.

Comment: Do you think you could include your answer in the wiki answer above?

Comment: The reason I would rather not is that mine is written in a different style.